Send file content to MSMQ from powershell
I need to test some message queue processing functions and for that I need to push a message with contents of a json file. I'm currently forced to do it without using any 3rd party applications and as such, through powershell.
I've tried doing it this way.
Get-MsmqQueue -Name "queue" | Send-MsmqQueue -Body (Get-Content -Raw -Path "path_to_json") -Transactional

But I'm getting this as a result.
Send-MsmqQueue : There was an error generating the XML document.
At line:1 char:36
+ ..." | Send-MsmqQueue -Body (Get-Content -Raw -Path ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Send-MsmqQueue], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.SendMSMQQueueCommand

Operation works correctly if I write a simple string for -Body instead of the result of Get-Content), but pasting contents of file this way is not really feasible.

How big is the file? There’s a limit of 4mb for msmq messages - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/msmq/ms711436(v=vs.85)#maximum-message-size

I have had success in the past sending a message to MSMQ using a memory stream. Below is a Function I use to accomplish this:
The parameters:

$queueName = The queue name as it is displayed in the Get-MsmqQueue command
$message = The body of the message as a string

Function:
Function SendMSMQmessage
{
    Param(
        $queueName,
        $message
    )

    $queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queueName
    $utf8 = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    $msgBytes = $utf8.GetBytes($message)
    $msgStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
    $msgStream.Write($msgBytes, 0, $msgBytes.Length)
    $msg = New-Object System.Messaging.Message
    $msg.BodyStream = $msgStream
    $queue.Send($msg)

    Write-Host "ORIGINAL MESSAGE: " -ForegroundColor Yellow 
    $message

}

Using the Function (example):
SendMSMQmessage -queueName "Server\QueueName" -message "I am a test"

